# Iteration vs. range created via Union

Tags: vba, excel

The following code adds each value over 10 it founds in the sheet to the "Over10" range:

```
Sub IterateOver10()

Dim Over10 As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    If cell > 10 Then
        If Over10 Is Nothing then
            Set Over10 = cell
        Else
            Set Over10= Union(cell,Over10)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

I want to iterate through each item in "Over10" with a loop and check if it exists in another range. The problem is that the following iteration:

```
For each cell2 in Over10
    ' check if exists in another range
next cell2
```

won't work for a range declared this way because it seems to use the range from cell2 to (cell2 + the count of Over10) instead. Any suggestions for a workaround. Should I use arrays instead?

Thanks,
Bartek

Comment: Arrays are much faster than looping over cells on a worksheet.

Comment: it will iterate each item in Over10. That will be a number of ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this. One of them is with nested loops, where you iterate through both of the collections (or ranges or arrays, as you wish):

```
Sub IterateOver10()

    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim Over10          As Range
    Dim myCollection    As New Collection
    Dim myCollection2   As New Collection

    Dim iterator        As Variant
    Dim iterator2       As Variant

    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If myCell > 10 Then
            myCollection.Add (myCell)
        End If
    Next myCell

    myCollection2.Add 15
    myCollection2.Add 16

    For Each iterator2 In myCollection2
        For Each iterator In myCollection
            If iterator = iterator2 Then
                Debug.Print iterator
            End If
        Next iterator
    Next iterator2

End Sub
```

Thus, if your input looks like this at the beginning:

[image]

in your collection named `myCollection` you would have 12, 13, 14 and 15. Then in the `myCollection2` you will find that 15 is in both collections and it will be printed on the immediate window.

Comment: I have tried this code but nothing ever gets printed in the Immediate window (the code never gets to "Debug.Print" part). Also see my post below.

Comment: @barciewicz - just open an empty Excel file and put my code there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vityata, I have tried you suggestion and came up with the following code to compare values in a newly created collection with worksheet names of another workbook and hide those worksheets where a match is not found:

```
Sub Over10Vol2()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim Over10 As New Collection

For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If myCell > 10 Then
        Over10.Add (myCell)
    End If
Next myCell

Dim Final As Workbook
Set Final = Workbooks("testbook")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell2 As Variant

For Each ws In Final.Worksheets
    For Each cell2 In Over10 ' jumps from here...
        If ws.Name <> cell2 Then
            ws.Visible = False
        Else
            ws.Visible = True
        End If
    Next cell2
Next ws                       ' to here

End Sub
```

This won't work however because the code omits the If clause in the second For Each loop completely, it just jumps from "for each cell2..." straight to "next **ws**". 
Thanks for any suggestions